# Apache2 + nginx + docker keycloak

Tags: docker, nginx, apache2, keycloak

I have an issue with access to Keycloak admin console via bundle Apache2 + nginx + keycloak.

I can pass a Keycloak authorization process (in Keycloak Web UI) but then Keycloak redirects me to an empty page /auth/admin/master/console/.

If I omit Apache and connect via bundle nginx + keycloak then everything is ok: page /auth/admin/master/console/ is not empty.

Did someone face with such situation?

Unfortunately, for technical reasons I can't provide Apache and nginx config.

Comment: Do you have any reason to use Apache and Nginx both as reverse proxies together?

Comment: The issue was caused by anti-clickjacking setting in Apache: `Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY`.
I've added the next line: `Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM <site_domain_name>"` and now it works. 
@XtremeBiker - thank you for participating.